# Error when connecting to AzureAD powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am using powershell to extract O365 license information, the command I am using to connect to AzureAD is:

```
$cred = get-credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred
```

This script runs successfully when using my own O365 credentials however when I use the newly created service account (after the sync has completed) I get the following error:

```
*connect-azuread : One or more errors occurred.: parsing_wstrust_response_failed: Parsing WS-Trust response failed
At line:4 char:1
+ connect-azuread -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD*
```

The company does use multi-factor authentication however it is turned off for the service account

When running command:

```
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred
$error[0] | select *
```

I get the following output:

```
*ErrorRecord                 : One or more errors occurred.: parsing_wstrust_response_failed: Parsing WS-Trust response failed
WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False
Message                     : The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 
                              One or more errors occurred.: parsing_wstrust_response_failed: Parsing WS-Trust response failed
Data                        : {System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo}
InnerException              : 
TargetSite                  : Void CheckActionPreference(System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionContext, System.Exception)
StackTrace                  :    at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception 
                              exception)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object 
                              inputToProcess)
                              --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                                 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
                                 at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
HelpLink                    : 
Source                      : System.Management.Automation
HResult                     : -2146233087*
```

Does anyone have any clues as to why this is happening? Any advice/workarounds would be great.

Comment: Can you run `Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred; $error[0] | select *` and post the result? There may be more helpful information in the stack trace.

Comment: hi @Persistent13, edited question to show output of error command